# Thymeleaf - output variable without a tag

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I use Thymeleaf as a templating engine and I usually output variable value like this:

in Java I set:

```
ctx.setVariable("tester", "hello");
```

and in html template I output:

```
<span th:text="${tester}"></span>
```

This works great, but I would like to output a variable without the need of a tag. Something following would be great:

```
${tester}
```

Unfortunately it does not work. My goal is to avoid unnecessary tag to output the variable value. Is this possible to do with Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*My goal is to avoid unnecessary tag to output the variable value. Is this possible to do with Thymeleaf?*

Yes this is possible. You can use the Thymeleaf synthetic `th:block` tag (see [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#synthetic-thblock-tag)).

Example template excerpt:

```
<body>
    <th:block th:text="${tester}"></th:block>    
</body>
```

This renders the following HTML:

```
<body>
    hello    
</body>
```

Only the variable is displayed.

Comment: This can be shortened to `<th:block th:text="${tester}"/>`.

Answer (score 4):

Use Thymeleaf expression inlining ([docs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#expression-inlining)) using either `[[...]]` or `[(...)]`. With expression inlining, you do not need to use synthetic tags.

Example:

```
<body>
The value of tester is [[${tester}]].
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thymeleaf triggers on the "th:" tag and as far as I know thats the only way.
The behaviour you describe works with JSF.

Best regards

Ben

Answer (score 1):

I also managed to figure out some workaround:

```
<span th:text="${tester}" th:remove="tag"></span>
```

th:remove removes span tag, but preserves content.